# Patterns in roots of integer-coefficient polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Below are shown two displays of all the roots of polynomials
$$c_n x^n + c_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 x + c_0 \;=\; 0$$
with each coefficient $c_i$ an integer $|c_i| \le M$
(including $c_i=0$).
No doubt this is all well-known, but
I would be interested to learn what results explain the patterns
in the distributions, especially the holes, both surrounding
the real axis—in both shape and location—and the off-axis holes, 
perhaps more evident in the degree-$3$
plot than in the degree-$5$ plot.

---

[image: roots_n3c6]

          

<sup>Roots of polynomials of degree $\le 3$ and integer coefficients $|c_i| \le 6$.</sup>

---

[image: roots_n5c5]

          

<sup>Roots of polynomials of degree $\le 5$ and integer coefficients $|c_i| \le 5$.</sup>

---

**Addendum**. User j.c. cited the [article by John Baez](http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/) 
on Dan Christensen's 
impressively detailed images,
one of which I include below:

---

[image]

---

Comment: More information and more images can be found here http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/ . This old question is also related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51732/perron-number-distribution

Comment: @j.c.: A direct hit! Puts my images to shame.

Comment: For the special case M=1 (which is already complicated enough), see the recent publication MR3719268 
Calegari, Danny; Koch, Sarah; Walker, Alden: 
Roots, Schottky semigroups, and a proof of Bandt's conjecture. 
Ergodic Theory Dynam. Systems 37 (2017), no. 8, 2487–2555.

Comment: The link to John Baez's page in the above comment no longer works. A current link is https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/ .

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $P(z)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients $|c_j| \le M$ and $z \ne 0$.  If $c_k$ is the first nonzero coefficient, 
$$|P(z)|/|z|^k \ge |c_k| - \sum_{j=k+1}^d |c_j| |z|^j \ge 1 - \frac{M |z|}{1-|z|} >0 \ \ \text{if}\ \ |z| < \frac{1}{1+M}$$
This explains the hole around $z=0$.  For the holes around $z=\pm 1$, first translate $z \to z\pm 1$.